# php ltrim not grabbing beginning dash

Tags: php

looking for a solution to my problem.
searching this place and google for an answer but can't gain much ground.

basically I want to remove "Issue 119 - " from a title.

so far I got the "Issue 119" to be removed but the " - " is persistent sadly
can anyone help me. would love it if I could amend the $cut variable line

$grissueno is from the custom field in my wordpress post = 119 string.

the_title presents the string "Issue 119 - Editorial: Troubled on every side" (example title)

```
<?php 
$cut = "Issue " . $grissueno; //joining the word issue and dynamic number together
$title = the_title('','',false ); //telling wordpress to let php use the title string
$trim = str_replace($cut, "", $title); //cutting out the Issue 119
echo ltrim($trim, " - "); //trying to remove the dash but failing
?>
```

thanks for any help

Comment: Perhaps a review of http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php would help

Comment: yes sorry I noticed I posted an edited code was trying loads of different things before i posted think its was str_replace :/ 
echo ltrim($trim, "- ");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `$cut = "Issue " . $grissueno;` to `$cut = "Issue " . $grissueno . " - ";` and forget about `ltrim()`.

Comment: for some reason because of the " - " it doesn't remove the $cut string :/ not really sure whats going on

Comment: oh thanks for the fixes guys >_< all mega helpful found out it was a &#8211; not a dash 
used 65Fbef05's answer but amended it like this.

    $cut = "Issue " . $grissueno . " &#8211; ";

thanks v much

Answer (score 3):

ltrim only takes two arguments. the string to trim, and a list of characters that are trimmable:

```
$trim = ltrim($title, "- ");
```

is what you want. Yours is trimming an empty string (`""`).

Comment: yea this is what i wanted to post originally sorry about that... it doesnt seam to work... dunno why tho

Comment: Are you sure that's a dash in the text? Could be an &ndash; or even an &mdash;

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$title = "Issue 119 - Editorial: Troubled on every side";
echo preg_replace('/Issue \d+ - (.*)/', '$1', $title);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the whole lot with: (**EDITED**)

```
echo ltrim(str_replace("Issue $grissueno",'',the_title('','',FALSE)),"- \t\n\r\0\x0B");
```